# Ionic 2 remove line under ion-refresher

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to remove the border under the `ion-refresher` element that appears when user pulls down. I have tried no-border no-shadow and custom css with `!important` but nothing seems to remove it, how can I remove the line under the ion-refresher that appears when a user pulls down

```
       <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" 
          no-border no-shadow style="border:none !important; box-shadow: none !important">
            <ion-refresher-content no-border no-shadow style="border:none !important">
            </ion-refresher-content>
       </ion-refresher>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove border-top. Add this to the css of your page:

```
.has-refresher>.scroll-content {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ion-refresher does not have the border. The border is part of ion-content > div.scroll-content

[image]